# Easy Scroll-Based Animations using CSS Custom Properties

Tags: javascript, css, safari, css-animations, css-variables

Now that support for custom css properties is becoming widespread, I had in mind to use them to simplify the creation of scroll-based animations. In Javascript, I'm using style.setProperty('--customProperty', value) to adjust the custom properties on specific elements as the user scrolls.

It works beautifully in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari 10.

**But**, in Safari 9.1 (which *does* support custom properties), I can only set the property *once*. After having been set, it will not update to a new value.

I've got it all in CodePen: https://codepen.io/kirkhadden/pen/JJbXmE/

```
// Have we scrolled since the last frame? 
if (position != wrapper[0].scrollpos) {

  // Keeps updating accurately every frame:
  window.log.text(position);

  // Only happens on the first frame:
  wrapper[0].style.setProperty('--scrollpos', position+'px', '');

  wrapper[0].scrollpos = position;

} else { // No Change

  return false;

}
```

I can't find any information or even mention of this behavior. I've tested other, simpler uses of style.setProperty() in Safari, and I continue to find that once a property is set, Safari won't update the same property, even if I try to remove the property first.

Is this a bug in Safari 9.1? Is there a work-around? Is there another way to use javascript to set css variables?

---

#### Update

So, instead of style.setProperty, I could instead use jQuery's .attr() method to set the property. It's not ideal, since that will overwrite any other style properties, but it works for this.

The bigger problem is that this whole solution is based on the idea of setting ordinary css animations on all my animated elements, but setting the play-state to 'paused', and then using javascript to manipulate the animation-delay according to the scroll position. This allows me to take advantage of inheritance to animate lots of things with minimal DOM manipulation.

Once again, Safari 9.1 is the road block, since it appears that unlike Chrome or Firefox, if the play-state is 'paused', Safari does not start the animation at all, and ignores the animation-delay.

Comment: Seems like data attributes would be better if you are using it to hold data

Comment: Well, I am not using it to hold data, I'm using it as a custom css property. Check out: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/04/start-using-css-custom-properties/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to polyfill CSS variables via JavaScript

For example:

```
let variables =
{
  color: "red",
  border: "2px solid blue"
}

// Get STYLE tag
let style = document.getElementById('custom');
// Save its original text
style.dataset.source = style.innerHTML;
function updateStyle()
{
    // Replace variables names with their values
    style.innerHTML = style.dataset.source.replace(/@(\w+)/g, function(match, name)
    {
        return variables[name];
    });
}

updateStyle();
```

Now you can use `@variableName` in your CSS and it'll be replaced with value of `variables.variableName`

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/JacobDesight/v7mqps84/

@EDIT

You can even create a function for settings variables:

```
function setProperty(name, value)
{
    variables[name] = value;
    updateStyle();
}
```

Now you just simply do something like:

```
setProperty('color', 'green');
```

And it will automatically update styles.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/JacobDesight/v7mqps84/1/